# XML change Layout button crashing app

Tags: java, android, xml

I have made a simple app because I am just starting with android. I have made a button to change the layout, but after testing it crashes the app every time.
here is my code

```
package nathanschmidt.nathan;


    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.widget.NumberPicker;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
TextView numberView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    numberView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numberview);
    NumberPicker numberPicker = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);
    numberPicker.setMaxValue(10);
    numberPicker.setMinValue(0);
    numberPicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
    numberPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(
            new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {

                    int color;
                    if (newVal < 1) {
                        color = Color.parseColor("#000000");
                    } else if (newVal < 2) {
                        color = Color.parseColor("#01093B");
                    } else if (newVal < 3) {
                        color = Color.parseColor("#000C57");
                    } else if (newVal < 4) {
                        color = Color.parseColor("#000F73");
                    } else if (newVal < 5) {
                        color = Color.parseColor("#00128a");
                    } else if (newVal < 6) {
                        color = Color.parseColor("#00159E");
                    } else if (newVal < 7) {
                        color = Color.parseColor("#0017B0");
                    } else if (newVal < 8) {
                        color = Color.parseColor("#001AC4");
                    } else if (newVal < 9) {
                        color = Color.parseColor("#001FE8");
                    } else {
                        color = Color.parseColor("#0022FF");
                    }

                    numberView.setTextColor(color);

                }
            });
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.about);

    // Watch for button clicks.
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.change);
    button.setOnClickListener(submitListener);
}

private OnClickListener submitListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
};
```

xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@drawable/os2">


<TextClock
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/numberview"
    android:textSize="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<NumberPicker
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/numberPicker"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="change"
    android:id="@+id/change"
    android:layout_below="@+id/numberPicker"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Comment: Post the crash stack trace

Comment: Why are you setting your content view twice? Also: why are you changing it from one layout to the next?

Comment: I thought that if i could do that i could change the design simply. unless there is a way to change the xml with a button press.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's crashing actually is those two lines of code

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.about);
```

You are here calling `Activity` class `onCreate()` method twice which is not a good practice at all and you are changing the layout in the `setContentView()` method and then when you are using the numberView you initialized from the **activity_main** layout while your current layout is the **about** layout.  I'm wondering what Exception did you get is it `NullPointerException` or `IllegalStateException`.

Comment: That worked! Thanks! Now i am wondering how to make that change layouts. Is that possible?

Comment: That is possible but when you call `setContentView()` you are inflating a new layout for the activity so you need to reinitialize your views (Buttons, TextViews...) again and don't use any View that is initialized from the layout you are not setting right now.